# List directory contents recursively to given depth

Tags: directory, ls

How can I list directory contents recursively, but only until a specified depth? I'm trying to do the equivalent of `ls -R --depth 2` with unix tools.

Comment: Do you mean you want to list every sub directory in a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply with **`find`** tool:

```
find . -maxdepth 2
```

---

> **-maxdepth *levels***
>   Descend at most `levels` (a non-negative integer) levels of directories
>   below the starting-points.